# PyQt5 PushButton gradient animation

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyside

I am trying to make an animated transition for a QPushButton.

This is the Stylesheet which the button currently has.

```
QPushButton{
border-radius:5px;
background-color: rgb(49,  56,  68);
}
```

I want to make an animation which goes from the first stylesheet to the second one:

```
QPushButton{
border-radius:5px;
background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0.2, x2: 1, y2: 1,
                    stop: 0 rgba(53, 84, 232,150), stop: 1 rgba(73, 104, 252,255));
}
```

in a smooth way but i haven't found any solution to do this.

Comment: There is no direct way to do so, as Qt animations don't work with gradients. They do work with colors, so a combination of two animations might work, but there are three questions here. 1. How the transition between those two states should happen? There are various ways in which a plain color can transform into a gradient. 2. When? 3. Is this supposed to work for any button, or just for one?

Answer (score 0):

Gradient color codes don't work here. I think you can use gradient background images.

Comment: What are you referring to? Qt stylesheets [support Qt gradients](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#gradient), the problem is in the management of the animation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Made something similair to what i wanted. Doesnt fully work but thats just the first piece of code i wrote.

```
        self.timer1 = QTimer()
        self.timer1.setInterval(4)


    def transitionthread(self, button):
        global r,b,g,r2,g2,b2,rd,gd,bd,rd2,gd2,bd2

        if(r != 53):r += 1
        else:
            rd = True
            pass
        if(g != 84):g += 1
        else:
            gd = True
            pass
        if(b != 232):b += 1
        else:
            bd = True
            pass

        if(r2 != 73):r2 += 1
        else:
            rd2 = True
            pass
        if(g2 != 104):g2 += 1
        else:
            gd2 = True
            pass
        if(b2 != 252):b2 += 1
        else:
            bd2 = True
            pass

        button.setStyleSheet("""
QPushButton {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0.2, x2: 1, y2: 1,
                    stop: 0 rgba(%s, %s, %s,150), stop: 1 rgba(%s, %s, %s,255));
}
"""%(r,g,b,r2,g2,b2))                                              #73, 104, 252, 255 is nich wie links

        if rd==True and gd== True and bd== True and rd2== True and gd2== True and bd2== True:
            print("Finished")
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(100, self.resetData)
            self.timer1.stop()

    def activate(self):
        sending_button = self.sender()
        if sending_button.objectName() == "pushButton_3":
            Module1 = True
            print(Module1)
        self.timer1.timeout.connect(lambda: self.transitionthread(button = sending_button))
        self.timer1.start()
    def resetData(self):
        rd,gd,bd,rd2,gd2,bd2 = False, False, False, False, False, False
        r = 49
        b = 68
        g = 56

        r2 = 49
        b2 = 68
        g2 = 56
        print("done")
```

Comment: Please consider providing a fully working [mre] as right now your code is incomplete and also not completely valid: despite the fact that you should *not* use globals, the variables set in `resetData` are not declared as such, so that function won't do anything. Please answer my comment in your question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).